# $(zw)^{n}=z^{n}w^{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Im answering the following question: [Prove that if $z=u$ is a solution of the equation $z^n=w$, then the other solutions have the form $u \rho ^j$ for $j=1,2,...,n-1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784387/prove-that-if-z-u-is-a-solution-of-the-equation-zn-w-then-the-other-soluti)

The only thing I need to know if my answer is right is if for $z, w \in \mathbb{C}$ we have that $(zw)^{n}=z^{n}w^{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Im not studying this as a complex analysis course so I just need to know if this is true or give me a glimpse if this is true. Im not looking for a fancy proof but a little sketch of the proof or link to the proof of this will be helpful. Thanks for helping

Comment: Yup, its true in any commutative ring. The proof is by induction, applying the commutative and associative laws of multiplication.

Comment: Integer powers of nonzero complex numbers are defined by repeated multiplication or division

Comment: Thanks for the hints, @LeeMosher

Comment: I apreciate your help @sharding. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I already did a proof by induction  that goes as follows: If we suppose $(zw)^{k-1}=z^{k-1}w^{k-1}$ then $$(zw)^{k}=(zw)^{k-1}(zw)=z^{k-1}w^{k-1}(zw)=z^{k}w^{k}.$$ The last step by the fact $\mathbb{C}$ is a commutative ring.